# Error when deploying Rails app to Ubuntu with 'gem unicorn' in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, unicorn

I'm deploying a Rails 3.2.8 app to Ubuntu. The server already runs the app with Unicorn and Nginx. 
unicorn -v returns unicorn v4.4.0

Adn rvm gem list shows:
unicorn (4.4.0)

Yet when I manually run 'gem install unicorn '4.4.0' it fails with the following. Any ideas why?

```
Installing unicorn (4.4.0)
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] with native extensions
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] 
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] 
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] /home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] checking for SIZEOF_OFF_T in ruby.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] details.  You may need configuration options.
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] 
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] Provided configuration options:
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] --with-opt-dir
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] --with-opt-include
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] --with-opt-lib
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] --with-make-prog
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] --without-make-prog
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] --srcdir=.
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] --curdir
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] --ruby=/home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] /home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] You have to install development tools first.
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] from /home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `block in try_compile'
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] from /home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:443:in `with_werror'
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] from /home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `try_compile'
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] from /home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:686:in `macro_defined?'
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] from /home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:822:in `block in have_macro'
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] from /home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] from /home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] from /home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] from /home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] from /home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] from /home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] from /home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] 
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] from /home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:821:in `have_macro'
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] 
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] 
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] Gem files will remain installed in /rails_apps/eg/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.4.0 for inspection.
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] Results logged to /rails_apps/eg/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.4.0/ext/unicorn_http/gem_make.out
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] 
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] An error occurred while installing unicorn (4.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] Make sure that `gem install unicorn -v '4.4.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Here's the content from what I *think* is the relevant mkmf.log

```
have_macro: checking for SIZEOF_SIZE_T in ruby.h... -------------------- yes

"gcc -I/home/evergreen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/home/eg/.rvm/usr/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC   -c conftest.c"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: #include <ruby.h>
4: /*top*/
5: #ifndef SIZEOF_SIZE_T
6: # error
7: >>>>>> SIZEOF_SIZE_T undefined <<<<<<
8: #endif
/* end */

--------------------

have_macro: checking for SIZEOF_LONG in ruby.h... -------------------- yes
```

Comment: Can you find a file called `mkmf.log` and post any relevant contents?

Comment: I have a bunch of files with that name but I just added the contents of the one I think is relevant to the post.

Comment: Sounds like a wired behavior maybe update the compiler or build the gem yourself with gmake :(

Comment: I just realized that unicorn 4.4.0 is already installed and it's what's running in this rvm gemset. so weird that it won't install again.

Answer (score 1):

make sure to install everything from requirements:

```
rvm get head
rvm requirements
```